# GulpJS: I don't want gulp-ruby-sass to loop through all sass files

Tags: ruby, node.js, sass, gulp, glob

This is the code I've written to make gulp watch all my SASS files, which works great ( I love it ),

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('../../_dev/_sass/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(rubysass({
        compass: true
      }))
      .pipe( minifyCSS() )
      .pipe( gulp.dest('../../') );
});
```

For some reason, when I tell the **CMD** to run gulp and I make a change to an *scss* file, the **CMD** loops through and updates all *scss* files within the specified directory, (I only want it to update the one I changed).

**EDIT: It actually loops through all *css* files, not he *scss* files.**

I've searched if there's anything that can stop it from globbing like that and sadly found nothing yet. There's nothing written in the [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) either if I read through it correctly.

I have an assumption that the part where I declared the *gulp.src()* as being set to watch all directories could be the reason why this is happening. Whereas I've applied this same style for my LESS and CoffeeScript environments and am not given this problem.

Is there a plugin or a minor detail I'm missing out that can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[gulp-changed](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed)** for this kind of purpose, to pass only through modified files. You have to specify the `dest` of your task to `changed` and do just as before:

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('../../_dev/_sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(changed('../../'))
    .pipe(rubysass({ compass: true }))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../'));
});
```

Comment: Hello, this doesn't seem to be making a difference. I've also written `changed('../../', { cwd : process.cwd() })` and it still loops through all the CSS files. Sorry, I said it loops through all the _scss_ files in my question but it's actually looping through the CSS files. Could this be to do with compass? I also tried to see if a difference is made using [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-newer), but this sin't working for me either.

Comment: Prefer *gulp-changed*, it's more active. Yeah it might be the use of *compass*, there is a lot of issues with it, since it's not using the standards for outputting the files [link](https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass/issues/2#issuecomment-31463516)